# How many block from main memory could be mapped to the same cache block?

Tags: caching, memory, embedded, riscv

What is the best amount of main memory address to map to the same cache block?

I want to give an example to clarify my question.

Assume we want to map 512 KB main memory to 4 KB cache. If we choose to create a direct mapped cache: we are going to map 128 main memory addresses to the same cache block? Is it too much? How to know?

Comment: What makes you think an answer **exists**? Can you name 3 factors that would influence this trade-off? Remember, cache is usually optional.  Intel's 8086 chip had 6 bytes of cache,  so even a little bit can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough information to say how many blocks of main memory would map to the same cache line.  What's missing is the block size: number of bytes per block.

As to whether any given cache is sufficient, that is a question of the job, also know as the workload — different workloads/jobs will exhibit different behaviors.  The same job/program with different sets of input can exhibit different behaviors.  Actual experimentation is pretty much the only way to know, but no matter what it will be a judgement call as to whether any given settings are "good enough".

When you have thrashing of cache lines, as is possible with direct mapped cache, that is detrimental to performance, so designers who identify this will try to fix that.

Software designers may chunk the data differently using algorithms to mitigate this given existing hardware they have to work with.

Hardware designers can implement different caching strategies, ranging from larger caches, to 2-, 4-, 8-way set associativity, to fully associative — for the hardware each of these incurs more hardware costs than a direct mapped cache (and may incur performance penalty as well), and further might price the component out of the market (make it too expensive) or exceed the process technology (i.e. be to big for one chip).

Comment: I assumed each main memory address point 1 word (8 bytes) data. Each cache block also holds 8 byte data.